# React send state with history.push

Tags: reactjs

So basically I have a list with products and when I click on one of them, this function is called and another page opened up.

```
const goToListAction = useCallback(
    (id = '') => {
      if (!id || id === newLabel) {
        history.push(ROUTES.newList, { prop1: method })
      } else {
        history.push(`${ROUTES.newList}/${id}`)
      }
    },
    [history, newLabel],
  )
```

now I want to access

```
const [method, setMethod] = useState<Method>(Method.Central)
```

the state of the method on the newly opened page. How do I do that?
As you see I tried passing it as a second argument (prop1) but location.state or location.state.prop1 gave me an undefined and is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are using react-router-dom 5. You can't use react state to reach that. The state you pass to history is location state.by the way the things you put into state should be string,number or boolean.

```
const location = useLocation();
const theMethodYouWant = location.state.prop1 //because you named it prop1
```